# SQL Statement help required

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

UPDATE

Finally managed to work it out! Thanks for all the help from everyone. If you spot any potential errors or scope for improvement in my query please let me know.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL_CAMPAIGNS C
INNER JOIN TBL_MEMBERS M
    ON C.campaign_MemberId = M.members_Id
INNER JOIN TBL_CAMPAIGNS_CHARITIES CC
    ON C.campaign_Key = CC.camchar_CampaignID
INNER JOIN TBL_CHARITIES CH
    ON CC.camchar_CharityID = CH.cha_Key
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    select recip_Chosen, count(recip_CampaignId) as ChosenCount
    from TBL_CAMPAIGNRECIPIENTS
    WHERE recip_CampaignId =  @campaign
    group by recip_Chosen
) CRC
on CH.cha_Key = CRC.recip_Chosen
WHERE C.campaign_Key = @campaign
```

Thanks!!!

///////////////////

After some really useful advice i decided to implement orbMan' suggestion as follows;

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL_CAMPAIGNS C
INNER JOIN TBL_MEMBERS M
    ON C.campaign_MemberId = M.members_Id
INNER JOIN TBL_CAMPAIGNS_CHARITIES CC
    ON C.campaign_Key = CC.camchar_CampaignID
INNER JOIN TBL_CHARITIES CH
    ON CC.camchar_CharityID = CH.cha_Key
WHERE C.campaign_Key = @campaign
```

This returns 1 row for each charity associated with a given campaign (as associated via TBL_Campaigns_Charities). However, i also have another table(TBL_CAMPAIGNRECIPIENTS CR) which details each person invited to take part in the campaign. On visiting the campaign page they can select one of the charities linked to the campaign.

Now i need to know how many people have chosen each of the associated charities(CR.recip_Chosen). Their details arent important. I just need to know how many people have selected each of the associated charities.

So something like;

```
COUNT CH.cha_Key, FROM CR WHERE CR.recip_Chosen = CH.cha_Key
```

but integrated into the statement above.

Thanks in advance.

ORIGINAL POST BELOW:

/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /

Hi,

I need to gain data from across 3 tables. The first two are straight forward and are currently grabbed as;

```
 SELECT * FROM TBL_CAMPAIGNS C
 JOIN TBL_MEMBERS M
 ON C.campaign_MemberId = M.members_Id
 WHERE C.campaign_Key = @campaign
```

The table 'TBL_CAMPAIGNS' contains various columns, five of which hold an int. This int refers to the key of the 3rd table 'TBL_CHARITIES'. How do i return the data of the third table in combination with the above?

Ive created the following so far;

```
 SELECT * FROM TBL_CAMPAIGNS C
 JOIN TBL_MEMBERS M
 ON C.campaign_MemberId = M.members_Id
 JOIN TBL_CHARITIES CH
 ON CH.cha_Key = C.campaign_Char1
 WHERE C.campaign_Key = @campaign
```

But, as you can tell, that only returns C.campaign_Char1. What about C.campaign_Char2, C.campaign_Char3, C.campaign_Char4, C.campaign_Char5 ?????

I did try this;

```
 SELECT * FROM TBL_CAMPAIGNS C
 JOIN TBL_MEMBERS M
 ON C.campaign_MemberId = M.members_Id
 JOIN TBL_CHARITIES CH
 ON CH.cha_Key = C.campaign_Char1
 AND CH.cha_Key = C.campaign_Char2
 AND CH.cha_Key = C.campaign_Char3
 .......
 WHERE C.campaign_Key = @campaign
```

But, of course this doesnt work!

Any suggestions / help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a denormalized design and that is why you are having difficulty querying it. It would be easier if (instead of columns campaign_Char1 through 5) you had a many-to-many table between TBL_CAMPAIGNS and TBL_CHARITIES. E.g., TBL_CAMPAIGNS_CHARITIES. This would contain a Campaign ID and a CharityID.

Then your query would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL_CAMPAIGNS C
INNER JOIN TBL_MEMBERS M
    ON C.campaign_MemberId = M.members_Id
INNER JOIN TBL_CAMPAIGNS_CHARITIES CC
    ON C.campaign_Key = CC.CampaignID
INNER JOIN TBL_CHARITIES CH
    ON CC.CharityID = CH.cha_Key
WHERE C.campaign_Key = @campaign
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL_CAMPAIGNS C
INNER JOIN TBL_MEMBERS M
    ON C.campaign_MemberId = M.members_Id
INNER JOIN TBL_CAMPAIGNS_CHARITIES CC
    ON C.campaign_Key = CC.camchar_CampaignID
INNER JOIN TBL_CHARITIES CH
    ON CC.camchar_CharityID = CH.cha_Key
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    select recip_Chosen, count(*) as ChosenCount
    from TBL_CAMPAIGNRECIPIENTS 
    group by recip_Chosen
) CRC
on CH.cha_Key = CRC.recip_Chosen
WHERE C.campaign_Key = @campaign
```

Comment: I prefer fixing the design over kludging the report too, up vote for that.

Comment: So, would TBL_CAMPAIGNS_CHARITIES contain upto 5 rows for each campaign?

Comment: I.e. one row for each of the potential charities allocates (e.g. C.campaign_Char1.... etc as in above example)?

Comment: Yes, if you want to retrieve all the data in one query, you woudl get duplicate rows. There are techniques for rolling the data up into one row if that is desired, but normally I would do more selective queries for whatever specific data I needed at that moment.

Comment: Ok thanks. I implemented this change to the structure. This brings me on to the next part of it. IVe updated the original question. Please take a look.

Comment: OrbMan, i messed up mate. I need to change "on CH.cha_Key = "CRC.recip_Chosen" to be "on C.campaign_Key = CRC.recip_CampaignId"

Cant get this to work without cocking up the results. Please help.

Comment: Why do you need to change it? Are you saying that you want to count the number of recipients per campaign? How does that relate to the requirement in your question saying you want to count how many people selected a given charity? The requirements are becoming foggy here.

Comment: At present it returns a count of everyone that has chosen that given charity. What i need it to do is return a count of everyone that has chosen a given charity within that campaign.

Answer (score 2):

First thought is that you'll have to join the TBL_CHARITIES table again for each reference you want to give.

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_CAMPAIGNS C
 JOIN TBL_MEMBERS M
 ON C.campaign_MemberId = M.members_Id
 JOIN TBL_CHARITIES CH1
 ON CH1.cha_Key = C.campaign_Char1
 JOIN TBL_CHARITIES CH2
 ON CH2.cha_Key = C.campaign_Char2
 JOIN TBL_CHARITIES CH3
 ON CH3.cha_Key = C.campaign_Char3
 JOIN TBL_CHARITIES CH4
 ON CH4.cha_Key = C.campaign_Char4
 JOIN TBL_CHARITIES CH5
 ON CH5.cha_Key = C.campaign_Char5
 WHERE C.campaign_Key = @campaign
```

I'm sure someone has a better solution though.

Comment: Cool, That works provided none of the 'C.campaign_Char[X]' are '0' or dont have a match in the TBL_CHARITIES. Evidently thats a fault in my use of JOIN. Any ideas?

Comment: If there is a potential of having fewer than 5 charities, you will need to LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN on the 5 joins to TBL_CHARITIES.

Comment: Also note that you'll have to explicitly name your columns in the SELECT clause, otherwise you will have 5 of each of the campaign columns with the same name (eg, there will be 5 columns named "cha_Key").

Comment: It actually appears to tag a suffix onto the end of each set of cha_keys, which certainly makes it easier to deal with.

Comment: Good catch on the LEFT JOIN, I was just copying and pasting... bad programmer, bad!

Comment: Thumbs up for helping though!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a bit on @OrbMan, run the following SQL to demonstrate how this plays out. It should show you what the tables look like, including the many-to-many @camp2char table.

```
set nocount on
DECLARE @camp TABLE (
    ID int,
    ID2 int,
    primary key (id)
)
DECLARE @memb table (
ID int NOT NULL,
primary key (id)
)
DECLARE @chars table (
ID int NOT NULL,
primary key (id)
)
DECLARE @camp2char table (
ID1 int NOT NULL,
ID3 int NOT NULL
)
insert into @memb (id) values(100);
insert into @memb (id) values(200);
insert into @memb (id) values(300);
insert into @chars (id) VALUES(1000);
insert into @chars (id) VALUES(2000);
insert into @chars (id) VALUES(3000);
insert into @chars (id) VALUES(4000);
insert into @chars (id) VALUES(5000);
insert into @camp (ID,ID2) VALUES(1,100);
insert into @camp (ID,ID2) VALUES(2,300);
insert into @camp2char (ID1,ID3) VALUES(1,1000);
insert into @camp2char (ID1,ID3) VALUES(1,2000);
insert into @camp2char (ID1,ID3) VALUES(1,3000);
insert into @camp2char (ID1,ID3) VALUES(1,5000);
insert into @camp2char (ID1,ID3) VALUES(2,2000);

PRINT '@camp';
select * from @camp;
PRINT '@memb';
select * from @memb;
PRINT '@chars';
select * from @chars;
PRINT '@camp2char';
select * from @camp2char;

select c.ID 'camp.id', m.ID 'memb.id', ch.id 'char.id' from @camp c
inner join @memb m
on c.id2 = m.id
inner join @camp2char c2ch
on c.id = c2ch.id1
inner join @chars ch
on c2ch.id3 = ch.id
where c.id=1
```

One effect of this approach is that, instead of one resultant row, your result row count will be equal to the number of matching charity rows that match the target campaign.

The benefit is that you can have any number of charities associated with any number of campaigns.

Also, if you ever have more than one member per campaign, you'll want to normalize it the same way (with a camp2memb table, for example).

**Output from script run on SQL SVR 2005**

```
@camp
ID          ID2
----------- -----------
1           100
2           300

@memb
ID
-----------
100
200
300

@chars
ID
-----------
1000
2000
3000
4000
5000

@camp2char
ID1         ID3
----------- -----------
1           1000
1           2000
1           3000
1           5000
2           2000

camp.id     memb.id     char.id
----------- ----------- -----------
1           100         1000
1           100         2000
1           100         3000
1           100         5000
```

Comment: Sure it does *something*. :) Hmmm... SQL Server 2000 here (w/2005 Mgt Studio), so maybe that's it. I did this in a query window set to show Text Results, though grid results works too. Are you running it in a query window or trying to put it in a stored proc or something?

Comment: running it on SQL2005 via manager software in a Script Editor window. Just shows 5 empty tables. If i put the PRINT statements after the SELECT statements it outputs the first 3 tables with data but not the last two tables.

Comment: Odd. If you remove the print statements altogether (they're not critical) what happens?

Comment: Everything other than '@camp' is empty.

Comment: @Munklefish - i don't know why you have no tables or data. I just got MSSQL 2005 running locally and ran this, thinking maybe MSSQL 2000 had something to do with it. It still runs fine for me. Since this isn't really the point of your question or my answer, i've included the output in the answer. The idea was to illustrate what the many-to-many linking table looks like and what the retooled SELECT w/JOIN returns (one row per matching link).